# Build forms with ArcMap

Tags: arcmap

We have a set of layers to which we want to attach some forms. I used to do this easily in QGIS, now our clients want to move to ArcGIS and they want to build a form to each feature class of the GDB. I did some researches and I found out that this could be done using Add-ins.

The client is not a developer, so he needs an easy way to create a simple form within ArcMap (the form that contains checkboxes for boolean fields, list of values, calendars, the button to load photos or files etc.).

How can we perform this function?

Answer (score 1):

If you license VBA then you could build the custom forms directly in the MXD? But as ESRI are actively discouraging VBA that may be a dead end. You could try exploring creating a python tool script to allow you to enter data 1 row at a time? But for a fully featured custom form then ESRI AddIns is the most likely solution. These would hook into edit events and expose the forms.

May be you could also explore ArcGIS Pro and tasks as an option? If they are making the move to the ESRI platform why bother investing time and effort in a software (ArcMap) where the writing is on the wall?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The client chose to work with Arcmap. Then as I said in QGIS you really can create a form very easily, you don't need to use qtdesigner for people who don't handle it. Is  ArcGIS have the same functionnalities to create a simple form. The clients are not developpers and I don't see how they can create forms with Addins.

Comment: ArcMap does not really have an equivalent to QGIS so if they want focused custom forms then they will need to employee a GIS developer to build it for them.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It's really disappointing that such a function is missing from ArcGIS